How to use COMSOL Multiphysics to simulate a magnetic soft robot?
I am trying to simulate a magnetic soft robot using COMSOL Multiphysics. Essentially you have a magnetic polymer with an embedded magnetization profile created during fabrication using very small ferromagnetic particles oriented precisely. These can react to an external magnetic field which is manipulated in magnitude and time, to control the behavior of the robot. I need to simulate such a robot on COMSOL Multiphysics.
The design consists of a cylinder, where there is an alternating magnetization profile along its body, which I defined by simply creating various magnetization models in specific directions on specific domains. Based of that, one would expect specific deformation patterns from an external field to behave in a particular way, but either the simulation breaks or the results simply do not conform to the theory. The goal is to get the robot to move like an inchworm.
In principle it should be relatively easy to achieve; define the magnetization, apply the external magnetic field, and analysis the deformation caused by the embedded magnetization profile of the robot. However, I can't seem to be able to achieve this in a robust or even accurate way. Any help is appreciated.
